# How to remove columns specified in an Excel file from a SAS table?

Tags: sas, proc-sql, import-from-excel

I have table in SAS like below:

TABLE 1

```
COL3  | COL2 | ...  | COLn
------|------|------|----
111   | ABC  | ...  | 12
222   | AAA  | ...  | 10.5
333   | app  | ...  | 5
...   | ...  | ...  | ...
```

And I have table in Excel file like below:

TABLE 2

```
GROUP| NAME  | DEFINITION
-----|-------|-------------
ABC  | COL1  | xxxxxxx
ABC  | COL2  | xxxxxxxxxx
BBB  | COL15 | xxxxxxxxx
...  | ...   | ...
```

And I need to remove from TABLE 1 (SAS table) variables which are listed in "NAME" column in TABLE 2 (Excel file).

So as a result i need something like below (using only example above but i have many more columns of course).

```
COL3  |  ... | COLn
------|------|----
111   | ...  | 12
222   | ...  | 10.5
333   | ...  | 5
...   | ...  | ...
```

How can I do that in SAS Enterprise Guide ?

Comment: Are you able to import the Excel file yourself?

Comment: Also, COL1 should not be in the resulting data, correct?

Comment: Why does the COL1 remains in your example's output if COL1 is present in the NAME column of the Excel file?

Comment: PeterClemmensen, Yes you are rigth COL1 and COL2 should be remove

Comment: Peter, Kermit - I edited my question, now is clearly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create sample dataset and `.xlsx` file

```
data have;
input col1-col5 ;
cards;
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
;
run;
```

[image]

Import the file

```
proc import datafile='/home/kermit/have.xlsx' 
        dbms=XLSX replace 
        out=have_xlsx(keep=NAME);
run;
```

Fill the `cols` macro variable with the list of distinct columns to drop from the `name` column

```
proc sql noprint;
    select distinct name into :cols separated by ' '
    from have_xlsx;
quit;
```

Drop the selected columns

```
data want;
    set have(drop=&cols.);
run;
```

As a result, only `col3` is kept

```
col3
 3
 8
```

---

**After your comment**

There are two ways

1. Play with the [`DKRICOND`](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lgref/z0208086.htm) option before the data step. It will suppress the error message that would normally be generated by trying to drop a variable that does not exist and will let your data step execute (not recommended)

```
option DKRICOND=NOWARN;
data want;
    set have(drop=&cols.);
run;
option DKRICOND=ERROR;
```

2. Adapt the current SQL query to only retrieve columns that exist in both tables

```
proc sql noprint;
    select distinct upcase(name) into :cols separated by ' '
    from have_xlsx
    where upcase(name) in 
    (select distinct upcase(name) from sashelp.vcolumn
        where upcase(memname) = 'HAVE');
quit;
```

Comment: Kermit, it looks good, I gave you best answet, thank you :)

Comment: Kermit, i used your code and i have error like that: ERROR: The variable COLxyz in the DROP, KEEP, or RENAME list has never been referenced. What can i do ?

Comment: Probably column COLxyz does not exists in my TABL1 1 (SAS table) but is in Excel file, so how can I modify this code to remove variables from exxcel file in it exists in sas table ?

Comment: Edited my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: Thank you Kermit :), could you have a look on my second question if you have a time ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74813248/how-to-drop-columns-from-sas-table-ends-with-defined-suffixes-if-such-columns-e