# How to drop columns with specific suffixes from a SAS table in SAS?

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I have table in SAS Enterprise Guide like below:

```
COL_DT    | COL_5  | ...  | COL_n
----------|--------|------|--------
10MAY2021 | 1      | ...  | xxx
15DEC2021 | 0.5    | ...  | xxx
09APR2020 | 12     | ...  | xxx
...       | ...    | ...  | ...
```

And I need to remove from above SAS table column which ends with: `_DT, _ID, _CP` **if columns with mentioned suffixes exist**

Expected output:

```
COL_5  | ...  | COL_n
-------|------|-------
1      | ...  | xxx
0.5    | ...  | xxx
12     | ...  | xxx
...    | ...  | ...
```

How can I do that in SAS Enterprise Guide ?

Comment: I think it is an old topic: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/want-to-drop-variables-with-same-suffix/td-p/201568

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create sample data set

```
data have;
    input col1-col5 col_dt col_id col_cp;
    cards;
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
;
run;
```

Create the list of columns to drop using the same technique as in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74810239/how-to-remove-columns-specified-in-an-excel-file-from-a-sas-table)

```
proc sql noprint;
    select distinct name into :cols separated by ' '
    from sashelp.vcolumn 
    where upcase(memname)='HAVE' and 
        (upcase(name) like '%^_DT' escape '^' 
        or upcase(name) like '%^_ID' escape '^' 
        or upcase(name) like '%^_CP' escape '^');
quit;
```

Drop the selected columns

```
data want;
    set have(drop=&cols.);
run;
```

As a result

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
 1     2    3    4    5
 9    10   11   12   13
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `proc contents` instead of the SAS column view

```
data have;
    input col1-col5 col_dt col_id col_cp;
    cards;
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
;
run;

proc contents data=have out=content noprint nodetails;run;

proc sql noprint;
    select distinct name into :cols separated by ' '
    from content 
    where upcase(memname)='HAVE' and 
        (upcase(name) like '%^_DT' escape '^' 
        or upcase(name) like '%^_ID' escape '^' 
        or upcase(name) like '%^_CP' escape '^');
quit;

data want;
    set have(drop=&cols.);
run;
```

Comment: Kermit, are you sure that this code is correct ? I used that and columns with mentioned suffexes still exist in my table ?

Comment: What is upcase(memname)='HAVE' and sashelp.vcolumn ?

Comment: You have to replace the `memname` by the name of your SAS table, in upcase. 
`sashelp.vcolumn` is a view that provides information about name, type, length, member and library name for all variables in all datasets in the current session.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `proc contents` instead of the SAS view. Edited my answer.

Comment: Kermit, it works, thank you I gave best answer! :)